# How Keep session in Swift 3.0 using UserDefaults.standard?

Tags: ios, swift3, userdefaults

I have two(2) swift 3.0 files.

Edited:

My goal is to keep the ViewController active/appear after login is success.
And I want to keep LoginVC active when logout button hit.

Everything works fine such as posting and read json data.

Edited:

**ViewController successfully active when loggedin, but when i hit logout button, stop and build it again, ViewController still not dismiss. It should be redirect to LoginVC**.

I think maybe something wrong with my **UserDefaults.standard** code.

My code as below

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad() }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
        if(!isUserLoggedIn){
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginview", sender: self)
        }
    }
    @IBAction func logoutData(_ sender: Any) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn");
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginview", sender: self)
    }
}
```

**LoginVC.swift**

```
import UIKit
class LoginVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var _login: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var _pass: UITextField!
    var login: String!
    var pass: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad() }

    @IBAction func loginData(_ sender: Any) {  
        login = _login.text
        pass  = _pass.text

        if(login == "" || pass == "") {
            return
        }
        else {
            let url     = URL(string: "http://localhost/login.php")
            let session = URLSession.shared

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"

            let paramToLogin = "login=\(login!)&pass=\(pass!)"
            request.httpBody = paramToLogin.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                else {
                    do {
                        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String]
                        {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                let success  = Int(json["message"]!)

                                if(success == 1){
                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
                                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize();
                                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    return
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to use `set(true, forKey: "yourKey")` instead of reading it once you are logged in

Comment: You also need to serialize  your JSON data before posting it https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization

Comment: yes. I already update the question . But comes another problem. When i tap logout button . It does not kill the session. .

Comment: Sorry if the code is too long.

Comment: No need to force synchronize

Comment: You need to fix  `request.httpBody = paramToLogin.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)`. JSON top level object needs to be a dictionary or an array, just create a dictionary, add your keys (login/pass) and values to it and serialize it using https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data method to get your JSON data

Comment: How to fix that line ? @LeoDabus

Comment: Swift2 sample will give you an idea http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145398/22328. Make sure you use `URL` instead of `NSURL` and `URLRequest` declared as variable instead of `NSMutableURLRequest` for your Swift3 code

Comment: During Logout also the value "true" is storing in UserDefaults.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys :D . appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code during Logout also the value "true" is storing in UserDefaults. I think this may be the issue.

Comment: yeah. i change it to 'false' . so far it works. But i'm not sure if my code above is the correct way to create login session page.

Comment: I think it is not a good approach. If user is not loggedIn, then you have to set the LoginVC as rootViewController. Once user loggedIn change the rootViewController to ViewController. Do the vice versa for Logout.

Comment: Can you take a look in this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711734/appdelegate-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-launchoptions-terminating-with-uncau .

Comment: I hope one of the developer answered the question, That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
let loginStroyBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"Login", bundle: nil)
let businessLoginViewController = loginStroyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BusinessLoginViewController") as! BusinessLoginViewController
let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Log Out", message: "Are You Sure to Log Out ? ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    self.present(businessLoginViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "isFirstTime")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "isLogIn")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "uid")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "hash")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "storeadminid")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "adminhash")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "store_id")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "isLogIn")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "login_id")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "password")
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(false, forKey: "islogout")
    }

    //self.tabBarController?.tabBar.resignFirstResponder()
}))

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    refreshAlert .dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}))

present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

I will be using this for logout also..
You can try this one, I will do it with my cell in logout button.