# AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions - terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, appdelegate

I'm trying to create login/protected page session page using Swift 3.0

Therefore, I created **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions** function in AppDelegate.swift as below

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let isUserLoggedIn:Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
        if(!isUserLoggedIn){

            let loginViewController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginview") as! LoginVC

            window!.rootViewController = loginViewController
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
        else{
            let protectedPage = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

            window!.rootViewController = protectedPage
            window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

It build successfully, But i got an error when apps run. The error as below

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier
>   'loginview''
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)

Comment: Check your project as error said - reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'loginview''

Comment: Already add 'loginview' in identifier . But it didn't read

Comment: May be cause of spelling. check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, you did not set the Storyboard ID of your LoginVC. Select the LoginVC in storyboard and set the storyboard ID as "loginview". See the image for reference

[image]

Comment: The storyboard ID is based on class name ?

Answer (score 3):

In the Storyboard select the LoginVC and in Inspector window give `loginview` identifier in the Storyboard ID

Comment: Already add 'loginview' in identifier . I'm not sure why it still give an error . .

Comment: did you try to clean the project and run again

Comment: opps . i forgot to set the Storyboard ID . Btw , thanks for the reply . Appreciate it :D . .